# Is it possible to include ListActivity with own layout in another layout?

Tags: android-layout

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) at *"6. Exercise: ListActivity with own layout"* is the custom list that I want to include in another layout. Is it possible?

The reason why I need this is to make layout that has header, (this) custom list and button. If I make textview or button in *that* *rowlayout.xml*, they got repeated in every list item.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: @Shivam Yes I know this, but I don't know where to put that java code in _MyListActivity_, so that list gets values.

Comment: One solution is to change my Activity to ListActivity and add _addHeaderView_ and _addFooterView_ .